# Visual WebGUI Configuration in IIS 10 still getting 404 error

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

I have configured Visual WebGUI with file extension *.wgx in the Handler mapping for Default website in iis 10 but still I am getting the 404 error.

[image]

Comment: Can you post any logs?

Comment: I am getting 404 error